# What are the options for non-americans to set up and operate a non-profit in the US?

Tags: non-profit

Could it be done if you are not a citizen of the US?

Comment: @BlueDogRanch Nice find. Unfortunately, the answer to that question isn't especially helpful, although (as usual) ohwilleke's comments are

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes, non-citizens can set up non-profits.**

Because non-profits are tax exempt, to become a non-profit, you have to apply to the IRS.

**Before you can apply to the IRS for non-profit status,** need to legally form your organization. Usually, that means incorporating your organization, although it can also be a trust or an association. In the US, forming organizations is controlled by states. You should double-check for your state, but as far as I can tell, all states allow non-citizens to form and run corporations.

**After you've set up your organization,** you can apply to the IRS for non-profit status. They will check your plans and decide whether you qualify. Because a 501(c)(3) does not pay taxes, the IRS imposes additional requirements.

**Where to go for more information:**

Because business organizations are formed under state law, you'll need to check the requirements for your state. If you are lucky, your state government has a helpful website. If not, searching for your state's name and "how to incorporate" should give you plenty of information.

USA.gov has a nice overview of the application process [here](https://www.usa.gov/start-nonprofit). The IRS has several publications and websites that you might find helpful: [here](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/p4220.pdf), [here](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/p557.pdf), [here](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/p4221pc.pdf), and [here](https://www.irs.gov/charities-non-profits/application-process). These cover everything from the general rules to nuts-and-bolts details about which forms to use.